# Alternation operator does not work as I expect in gawk match()

Tags: regex, awk

I am trying to run the below expression in gawk,

```
match(distinguished_name, /.+,([^=]+).+$|(DN1)=.+/, m);
```

The purpose is to be able to match the last distinguished name in the expressions `DN1=11,DN2=22` and `DN1=11`. When trying the regex in regex101 (PCRE!) it works well, but for some reason gawk will always try to match the second part `|(DN1)=.+` and not the first part.

Example:

```
$ cat test-regex.awk
BEGIN {
    distinguished_name1="DN1=11"
    distinguished_name2="DN1=11,DN2=22"
    match(distinguished_name1, /.+,([^=]+).+$|(DN1)=.+/, m)
    print "m[1]="m[1]", m[2]="m[2]
    match(distinguished_name2, /.+,([^=]+).+$|(DN1)=.+/, m)
    print "m[1]="m[1]", m[2]="m[2]

}
```

OUTPUT:

```
$ awk -f test-regex.awk
m[1]=, m[2]=DN1
m[1]=, m[2]=DN1
```

EXPECTED OUTPUT:

```
$ awk -f test-regex.awk
m[1]=, m[2]=DN1
m[1]=DN2, m[2]=
```

Anyone who knows why this happens and how to do it correctly?

BR Patrik

Comment: GNU awk or any awk doesn't support PCRE

Comment: @Inian Yes I know this, but there are not many websites where I can try gawk regex. Thus I have to do as good as possible. If you know how to do it to get the expected printout, feel free to answer :).

Comment: it is unclear what is the expected output - why do you have `DN2` for the output for `distinguished_name1` ?

Comment: @Inian It was a typo on my end. I have updated it. Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: Why do you even need regex for this - https://ideone.com/2V9XyK ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reading through https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Regexp.html, this is most likely a "leftmost longest" side-effect. `DN1=.+` matches starting at the first character and continues until the end of string.

Probably what you want with the "DN1" is the case where there are no commas, yes? In that case, that part would be `(DN1)=[^,]+$`

Or, just find the last one without alternation: `/([^,=]+)=[^=]+$/` -- find the sequence of non-comma non-equal characters followed by equal followed by non-equal chars until the end of string.